# How to display a variable value in JSP file

Tags: jsp, scriptlet

I want to display the value of variable named "id" in my code. The code is -

index.html(line 5)-

```
 <div class="marginTable" data-pubid="<%=id%>" data-count="5">
```

But whenever i am executing it, it is throwing error 
**An error occurred at line: 5 in the jsp file: /index.html
id cannot be resolved to a variable**. How to get out of this?

Answer (score 23):

To display the server side variables in jsp , you can use [implicit object](http://www.javatpoint.com/jsp-implicit-objects) `out`.

some thing like this,

```
<div class="marginTable"  data-count="5">
  <%=id%>
</div>
```

But using scriptlets is considered as the bad practice . so you may use EL for more info see this [How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files) as,

```
${id}
```

Answer (score 14):

I think this what you are looking for.....

page1.html...

```
 <a href="page2.jsp?id=5">Go</a>
```

page2.html

```
    <% String id = request.getParameter("id"); %>
    <div class="marginTable" data-pubid="<%=id%>" data-count="5"></div>
```